# How to sort dates in ascending order in pivot table by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I am trying to get a pivot table data set to sort dates in ascending order. The first step I took was to ensure the year was populated first. So, this is sorted by the year. However, the months are not sorted correctly. October (10) is showing before May (see photo).

How can I get both the year and month to sort in order?

[image]

Comment: based on seeing your screenshot, I'm sure your "dates" are actually text. you'll either need real dates or add a `0` in front of all your months that are less than 10.

Comment: I suggest you choose and right click one cell from the pivot table > Field Settings > Number format, check whether the format is Custom format `yy-m`.

Comment: @Emily I don't see a yy-mm option. Just mm-yy.

Comment: I figured it out. In my formula, I had `=TEXT(I51,"yy/m")` in stead of `=TEXT(I51,"yy/mm")`. So to @gns100 point, I needed the 0 in front of the other months.